# Opencv rotate camera mode

Tags: python, opencv

I want to rotate the camera view by 90 degree clockwise with an interrupt button. But the button's state goes back to it's default state when I click once and unpress the button. As a result, on clicking the button, the camera rotates for an instance and then goes back to the default mode in the while loop. How to solve this issue?

Here is my snippet:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2. VideoCapture(0) 

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('null', frame)
    
    if (button):
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
        cv2.imshow('null', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cap.release()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @prudence. Can you post function of button_a.is_pressed()?

Comment: @toyota Supra, Please check the button's function in the question. I have updated it.

Comment: @Prudence. you are missing cv2.waitKey(0). You should put after cv2.imshow()

Comment: @toyotaSupra, if I use cv2.waitKey(0) after the first imshow, the default camera mode is stuck as well just like the rotated view. I have a waitkey at the end my code for escape key before destroying the window.

Comment: I cannot test it because function of get_globalvar_value

Comment: sorry about that, it's an internal library. Thanks for you help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: you should use extra variable - `rotate = False` and later use `if button_a.is_pressed() and not rotate: rotate = True` and later `if rotate: ... cv2.rotate(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use extra variable - `rotate = False` - to keep this state

```
rotate = False

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # without imshow()

    if button_a.is_pressed(): 
         rotate = True

    if rotate:
         frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

    # outside `if`
    cv2.imshow('null', frame)
```

This way it changes `rotate` from `False` to `True` but never from `True` to `False`

---

**EDIT:**

If next press should rotate another 90 degrees (to 180) then it would need more complex code. It would check if `is_pressed()` in previous loop was `False` and in current loop is `True` - to run it only once when button is pressed long time.

Something like this.

I used normal `space` to test it.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

rotate = 0

is_pressed = False

previous = False
current  = False

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # without imshow()

    current = is_pressed
    if (previous is False) and (current is True): 
         rotate = (rotate + 90) % 360
         print(rotate)
    previous = current

    if rotate == 90:
         frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
    elif rotate == 180:
         frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_180)
    elif rotate == 270:
         frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    # outside `if`
    cv2.imshow('null', frame)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(40) & 0xff
    
    if key == 27:
        break
    
    is_pressed = (key == 32)
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Hi @furas, Thanks a lot for your answer. It didn't completely solve my problem but it helped me understand the concept that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2

cap = cv2. VideoCapture(0) 
button_is_pressed = false;

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if (button):
        button_is_pressed = not button_is_pressed 

    if(button_is_pressed)
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
        cv2.imshow('null', frame)
        
cap.release()
```

I would try something like this, when you press the button it changes the state of variable button_is_pressed, while still unchanged it keeps rotating image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Perhaps, I should have been clearer with my explanation. In my case, the button is a function call from a library I am using and cannot be assigned to any value.

I edited the code my question. This is exactly how my code is right now.

Comment: @pedro_bb7. You re miiing colon if(button_is_pressed): Also remove semi colon  and also nem false is not definebutton_is_pressed = False. Also the name button is not define